# Doctrine Many To Many Relation

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am not figuring out the proper Doctrine SQL/DQL for my problem.

```
class User{
    /**
     * Many Users have Many Groups.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ChatRoom", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_chats")
     */
    private $chats;
}

class ChatRoom{
    /**
     * Many Groups have Many Users.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="chats")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

The problem is that I need to list all Users inside my ChatRooms in the following structure, considering I am "User 1".

ChatRoom 1:

- User 1
- User 2

ChatRoom 2:

- User 1
- User 3

ChatRoom 3:

- User 1
- User 6

ChatRoom 4:

- User 1
- User 2
- User 3

In the second query I need to list all distinct users that are related to my ChatRooms that is different from my user.

- User 2
- User 3
- User 6

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Did you mean SQL or DQL? These are very different things.

Comment: Could be SQL or DQL, I have no problem with that! In Doctrine I use both, the problem is to return the followed data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$results1 = $qb->select('c, u')
    ->from('ChatRoom', 'c')
    ->join('c.users', 'u')
    ->join('c.users', 'u0', 'WITH', 'u0.id = :yourUserId')
    ->setParameter('yourUserId', $yourUserId)
    ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
var_dump($results1);

$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$results2 = $qb->select('DISTINCT(u)')
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->where('u.id != :yourUserId')
    ->join('u.chats', 'c')
    ->join('c.users', 'u1', 'WITH', 'u1.id = :yourUserId')
    ->setParameter('yourUserId', $yourUserId)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
var_dump($results2);
```

Comment: I've tried the code before posting the answer. I can check again if you tell what the problem is with the first query.

Answer (score 0):

For the first view just get all ChatRooms object and then loop over these objects and their asociated user collection somthing like

```
$ChatRooms = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:ChatRoom')->findAll();
```

Pass `$ChatRooms` to your view and loop through them

```
{% for ChatRoom in ChatRooms %}
    {{ ChatRoom.getName() }} /* display chat room name */
    {% for user in ChatRoom.getUsers() %}
        {{ user.getName() }} /* display user name */
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor%}
```

For second query to get distinct users for these chat rooms you can write similar DQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT u
FROM YourBundle:User u
JOIN u.chats
WHERE u.id != :userid
```

`:userid` this will be your user id which you don't want to include in returned results